# featherlight.js – How to transfer the close button to the inner-container

Tags: javascript, featherlight.js

Complete JS beginner here.
I'm trying to transfer the close button from the div `featherlight-content` to the div `featherlight-inner` to ensure that the close button is always visible, even when one is scrolling down.
Whenever I try it though I either manage to break the js and can't even open the lightbox or there's no close button in the code.
Here's the original version, with the close button in the `-content` div: [JSFiddle – Original](https://jsfiddle.net/nihilistenhymne/jfhm30xd/)
And here's a link to one of my attempts to transfer the button to the `-inner` div: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nihilistenhymne/bn2apfdw/)

The relevant code starts at line 152.

It would be awesome if someone could point out the mistakes I'm making.

Comment: If you move it inside the `inner`, it will still scroll, no?

Comment: As you can see in the JSFiddle, it's still scrolling but it won't put the button as I defined it in the JS in the HTML

Answer (score 0):

If you are not bothered to have it outside the box you can use

```
Position: fixed !important;
```